# Selecting countries that are being crossed by a river

Tags: qgis

Can you please advise how to mark countries that are being crossed by a river?
Meaning, to mark it not manually, but with a sort of function that I can later export this layer? I tried using Select by location... with no success. Created a buffer around the river. Whatever is in that buffer should be selected as the crossing country.
I am using QGIS.[image]

Comment: Show the settings you used in select by location

Comment: Crossed? or just intersected by the river?

Answer (score 6):

You dont need to buffer. Select By Location should work:

[image]

"But how can I work only with the selected countries?":

You can for example export the data by right click - save as.

Or filter your data which you can do manually by right click filter, or by using the selection and some python (which is much more fun):

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_ak_riks')[0] #Change to match your layer name
some_unique_id_field = 'ogc_fid' #Change to some numeric field you have in your data
idlist = [f[some_unique_id_field] for f in lyr.getSelectedFeatures()] #This lists all your selected ids
lyr.setSubsetString("{0} IN{1}".format(some_unique_id_field, tuple(idlist))) #This applies the filter
```

[image]

Comment: ... and after create a new field in your contry layer, update this field for only selected features.

Comment: Thanks! It seemed to work. But how can I work only with the selected countries? I need to show cities and their names and make some statistics, but only on marked countries. Is the way the manual filtering in 'Countries'? Or some more advanced option?

Comment: @Sandra, nice. Yes see updated answer. You might not need to filter at all. Many Processing tools have the option to only use selected features as input.